# Error "503 Service Temporarily Unavailable" when trying to scrape bitcointalk

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

I have been scraping a small amount of data once a day & the code was working before 5 days ago. Now I can't seem to get anything but a 503 error code when trying.

Here's a simple cut of the code causing the issues:

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

website = "https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?board=1.0"

req = Request(website, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
data = urlopen(req).read()
print(data)
```

which gives the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Clay/Desktop/python/airdrop/1.py", line 6, in <module>
    data = urlopen(req).read()
  File "C:\Users\Clay\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 223, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Clay\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 532, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\Clay\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 642, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Users\Clay\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 570, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Clay\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Clay\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 650, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 503: Service Temporarily Unavailable
```

any ideas? I am quite lost after changing the User-Agent and still having the same issue.

I also have multiple proxy servers that I've tried cycling through and it doesn't work on any of them.

Comment: Looks like they shut down their API

Comment: Sadly, yes it does. It looks like things have changed within the last few days. Any ideas on how to circumvent it? I thought scraping was pulling the HTML data, can websites restrict their HTML data that is seen when scraping?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Somebody have the solution for this problem?